# IBM Informix Spatial DataBlade select statement error

Tags: select, informix, spatial-query

I am using IBM Informix Spatial DataBlade module for some geo-specific data.
I am trying to find `points` in table `xmlData` lying in a specified region.
But I am getting this error for `select` statement.

```
SELECT sa.pre, sa.post 
FROM xmlData sa 
WHERE ST_Contains(('polygon((2 2,6 2,6 6,2 6,2 2)),sa.point)

    Query:
    select count(*) as mycnt fromText('polygon((2 2,6 2,6 6,2 6,2 2))',6),sa.point)
    Error: -201
    [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]A syntax error has occurred.
    (SQLPrepare[-201] at /work/lwchan/workspace/OATPHPcompile/pdo_informix/
     pdo_informix/informix_driver.c:131)
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement:

```
select count(*) as mycnt fromText('polygon((2 2,6 2,6 6,2 6,2 2))',6),sa.point)
```

is ill-formed; it has no 'FROM' clause.  Presumably, there is a space missing between 'FROM' and 'TEXT' in 'fromText'.

Be aware that TEXT is a data type in Informix.  I don't think it will cause problems here using it as a table name, but be cautious.